# How do electrical arcs carry less or more current with same supply voltages?

Tags: arc

With a powerful microwave oven transformer, big bright white arcs with more current are created.

With small flyback transformers driven by a simple oscillator, at the same voltage, arcs are thinner, purple, and have less current.

Assuming both devices are the same output voltage rating, how is it possible that one arc in the same air environment can "carry" more amperage than another arc knowing ohms law, with the same supply voltage, the current will stay equal with the same resistance independent of how much current I have available.

So I thought the only answer to this could be internal resistance, but wait that means the voltage decreases, thus a smaller arc, which is not true.

So how exactly can electrical arcs have higher current yet a constant supply voltage?

Comment: I figure inductance and frequency factors in somehow.

Comment: Even though the open-circuit voltage of both supplies is similar, the voltage is not what you think while the arc current is actually flowing. The smaller supply has a higher source impedance, and the voltage drops more than it does with the bigger supply.

Comment: The arc resistance is not fixed : as the large transformer can supply more current, it rips more air molecules apart to create a lower resistance arc. The small transformer has a higher impedance (probably inductance as Passerby says) which causes the voltage across the arc to reduce.

Comment: Ohms law doesn't do so well with a nonlinear Negative resistance. Compare apples to apples, use the same wave shape or none at all (DC), measure the voltage at the arc. Try to keep the arc length constant (vertical), as horizontal arcs arch from heated air, and become longer.